# Create select list from array

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I would like to create and display a select if an array exists. However, I get the error:

**undefined is not an object evaluating _studentYears2.default[this.props.selectedView].options**

Any ideas?

I have a function that generates the options:

```
createSelectItems() {
    const listItems = studentYears[ 
        this.props.selectedView
    ].options.map((option, i) => <Picker.Item label={option} value={i} />);
}
```

In my `render` I check for the `selectedView`

```
if (this.props.selectedView) {
        const listItems = studentYears[
            this.props.selectedView
        ].options.map((option, i) =>
            <Picker.Item label={option} value={i} />
        );

        selectList = (
            <Picker selectedValue={0} onValueChange={this.onChange}>
                {listItems}
            </Picker>
        );
    } else {
        selectList = null;
    }
```

And display the `selectList`:

```
     <View>{selectList}</View>
```

My sample data is:

```
   export default {
    studentYears: [
        {
            id: 0,
            title: "Year 1",
            value: 1,
            options: ["Firm 1", "Firm 2", "Firm 3"]
        },
        {
            id: 1,
            title: "Year 2",
            value: 2,
            options: ["Firm 2", "Firm 3", "Firm 4"]
        },
        {
            id: 2,
            title: "Year 3",
            value: 3,
            options: ["Firm 5", "Firm 6", "Firm 7"]
        }
    ]
};
```

I am import my data like this:

```
import { studentYears } from "../data/studentYears.js";
```

I would like to create a select list of options depending upon which studentyear is selected from a previous select list.

So in my first select list if I choose year 1. I would like a second select list to appear with the options Firm 1, Firm 2, Firm 3

Comment: remove `{}` from you import statement - `import studentYears from "../data/studentYears.js";`

Comment: Thanks, how can I map the 2nd object options? I'm getting map is not a function

Comment: So you would like to have 3 select lists and each of them should be defaulted with a value?

Comment: I've updated my question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created an example on how you might achieve this, I put selected year from the first select list on the state and depending on this value I find the selected object from `studentYears`, take its `options` and create another select list. Because the selected year is on the state, each time the user selects a different year the second select list will be updated with the options corresponding to the currently selected year.

So the second select list with options will always be in sync with the selected year. Here is the code:

```
class App extends React.Component {

  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      selectedYear: undefined,
      selectedOption: undefined
    };
    this.onSelectYearChange = this.onSelectYearChange.bind(this);
    this.onSelectOptionChange = this.onSelectOptionChange.bind(this);  
    this.getOptionsBySelectedYear = this.getOptionsBySelectedYear.bind(this);  
  }
  onSelectYearChange(event) {
    this.setState({ selectedYear: event.target.value });
  }
  onSelectOptionChange(event) {
    this.setState({ selectedOption: event.target.value });
  }
  getOptionsBySelectedYear() {
    const selectedYear = this.state.selectedYear;
    const selectedYearObject = selectedYear ? studentYears.find(s => s.value == selectedYear) : [];

    return selectedYearObject ? selectedYearObject.options : [];
  }
  render() {
    const { selectedYear, selectedOption } = this.state;
    const selectedYearOptions = this.getOptionsBySelectedYear();
    return (
      <div>
        <select onChange={this.onSelectYearChange} value={this.state.selectedYear}>
          <option value=''>None</option>
          { 
            studentYears.map((element) => (<option value={element.value}>{element.value}</option>))
          }
      </select>
      <br />
      {selectedYear && (
          <select onChange={this.onSelectOptionChange} value={selectedOption}>
            <option value=''>None</option>
            {
              selectedYearOptions.map((option) => (<option value={option}>{option}</option>))
            }
          </select>)
      }
    </div>
    )
  }
}
```

Here is a working example on [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/00ozyqol6p).

Answer (score 0):

```js
const studentYears = [
    {
        id: 0,
        title: "Year 1",
        value: 1,
        options: ["Firm 1", "Firm 2", "Firm 3"]
    },
    {
        id: 1,
        title: "Year 2",
        value: 2,
        options: ["Firm 2", "Firm 3", "Firm 4"]
    },
    {
        id: 2,
        title: "Year 3",
        value: 3,
        options: ["Firm 5", "Firm 6", "Firm 7"]
    }
];
class SelectRenderer extends React.Component {


render() {
 return (
  <select>
   {
    studentYears.map((element) => {
     return (
      <option value={element.id}>{element.value}</option>
     )
    })
   }
   </select>

 )
}
}
ReactDOM.render(<SelectRenderer />, document.getElementById("test"))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="test"></div>
```

A simple select implemented above.It may help to solve your issue.

Comment: Thanks, but I need the options for the object with the passed index. I get cannot read property 3 of undefined when I try and map the data

Answer (score 0):

```
  <select>
   {
    studentYears.map((element,index) => {
     return (
      <option value={element.id}>{element.value}</option>
     )
    })
   }
   </select>
```

You should not write `studentYears[key]` as it is already an array automatically map function will handle `key` and `index`.

Comment: Thanks but I get cannot read property map of undefined if I do that